# How can I find sheet music tabs and/or learn to play like M.Ward?

Tags: guitar, solos, rock-n-roll

For starters, the song [Shangri-la](https://open.spotify.com/album/5KqYEjZPHBchiXyudUzr5I?highlight=spotify:track:6B4EkplvUliaHIshivbSM9) would be good.  There is an ok tab on UltimateGuitar.com but it is just a simple one note at a time solo tab and there is a lot more complexity to this song and his playing in general. These types of melodys, and style of playing is the rabbit hole I would like to go down in my learning.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, but please read the Help Centre to realise that questions like this will get closed - with the reasons why.

Comment: tbh, tab is not a good way to learn how to copy someone's playing. Listen/trial/error gives a better end result, because that way you eventually **understand** how it was done.